# Is there any way to eliminate ERROR 1086 (HY000) in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export result of query to a text file 
using outfile command ERROR 1086 (HY000): File 'test.txt' already exists is prompted when i execute it second time.

```
        select * into outfile 'c:/test.txt' from test
```

I actaully want to replace the existing file.Is there any way to replace the existing file

Comment: You can't replace an existing file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the reference - file_name cannot be an existing file

[SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

So, you should remove old file yourself, or specify another name.

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL docs, [`SELECT ... INTO Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html):

> The `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'` form of `SELECT` writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. **file_name cannot be an existing file**, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed. As of MySQL 5.0.19, the character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation of the file name.

What you could do is use a client command such as `mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name` to generate the file.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to overwrite it.

Refer From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

Answer (score 0):

1. make **secure-file-priv=""** in file C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/my.ini
2. delete file 'c:/test.txt' from disk.
3. if you want to put the file in a folder, change "/" to "\" i.e. select * into outfile 'c:\folder\test.txt' from test
4. Also try to change the path to the file to another disk that has more rights, for example 'D:/test.txt'